# How to force all the comments to be moderated

Tags: disqus

Is there any way I can force **ALL** the comments to be enqueued for moderation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moderating your community](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466238-moderating-your-community), "Comment Pre-moderation":

> Pre-moderation options can be found your forum's Settings > Moderators page. You can choose to pre-moderate either all comments or comments made by guest profiles. You may also choose to screen comments which contain links as a way to control spammers and against posting inappropriate links.
>
> While this option isn't currently available in the Disqus 2012 forum settings, it can be enabled using the guide, [How to Enable Settings Missing from Disqus 2012](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/708758-settings-missing-from-disqus-2012). For more information on the differences between Disqus Classic and Disqus 2012, see [Introducing Disqus 2012 and F.A.Q.](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-disqus-2012-and-f-a-q-).

Comment: Thank you. Disqus "2012" was enabled by default, therefore I couldn't see the option. Next step: disabling "Stars" button...